# Why does MediaWiki insist it sent mail when it didn’t?

Tags: email, mediawiki

If someone, for example, used the password reminder, then MediaWiki states mail was being sent even if it didn’t.

In my example, my server uses Google G Suite MX settings, so I guess MediaWiki's default usage of PHP’s mail() fails. But still it insists mail was sent…

Comment: Questions about setup and configuration of web applications on your own server are off-topic on this site. Please ask in [meta.se] if there is a site for questions like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email sending typically happens asynchronously, so it would be an unreasonable level of complexity, if at all possible, to reliably track whether emails have been sent successfully. Given that email sending is a lossy operation (since the receiving party might always discard it during spam filtering), there is little value in it anyway; better to just design workflows with the assumption that emails might or might not arrive.